# Where are the logs created by Unreal Frontend?

Tags: unreal

I am trying to read errors generated by a build and cannot locate the log file. Which directory is it in?

Comment: Could you be more specific or describe the issue in more detail? What happens when you try to generate a build?

Comment: The question regards the location of the log file generated by Unreal Frontend. I have since found the Logs folder. Cheers.

Comment: @burntsugar Please post your answer as an answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about documentation for a specific tool which is potentially version-sensitive.